# Breadth First Search Implementation using adjacency matrix

Tags: c, data-structures, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement a work-around for this BFS algorithm from Coremen[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TTs2.png).I am using adjacency matrix and queue.

Consider the following graph:
Adjacency list:

1->2

2->4->3

3->NULL

4->3

5->2

Using the above algorithm am not able to traverse 5.
what is wrong with my implementation
I have included my implementation for reference

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    //Vertices represent the vertices of the graph

    //Color = {W,B,G}

    /*
     * W = White =>Means unvisited
     * B = Black =>Means visited
     * G = Gray =>Means discovered
     * colors and distances are stored in graph[i][0].color and graph[i][0].distance 
     * */

    struct Vertices{
        int data;
        char color;
        int distance;
    };

    struct node{
        int element;
        struct node *next;
    };

    /*
     * Here we check if vertex1 is adjacent to vertex2
     * Means graph[vertex1][vertex2].data !=0
     * */

    struct node *first = NULL;
    struct Vertices graph[8][8];
    int count = 0;

    void enqueue(int element){
        struct node *newNode,*currentNode,*prevNode;

        //Create a new Node
        newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newNode->element = element;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        //First node
        if(first == NULL){
            first = newNode;
        }

        //Any other node
        else{
            currentNode = first;
            while(currentNode != NULL){
                prevNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode->next;
            }
            prevNode->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    int dequeue(){
        int element;
        element = first->element;
        first = first->next;
        return element;
    }

    void displayGraph(int totalVertices){
        int i,j;
        printf("\nGraph");
        for(i=0;i<totalVertices;i++){
            for(j=0;j<totalVertices;j++){
                printf("\nData = %d Color = %c Distance = %d",graph[i][j].data,graph[i][j].color,graph[i][j].distance);
            }
        }
    }

    void displayQueue(){
        printf("\nQueue");
        struct node *currentNode;
        currentNode = first;
        while(currentNode != NULL){
            printf("--> %d",currentNode->element);
            currentNode=currentNode->next;
        }
    }

    int main(){
        int totalVertices;
        printf("\n Enter total vertices");
        scanf("%d",&totalVertices);


        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<totalVertices;i++){
            for(j=0;j<totalVertices;j++){
                printf("If %d adjacent to %d",(j+1),(i+1));
                printf("\nEnter 1 if yes. O if no");
                int value;
                scanf("%d",&value);
                graph[i][j].data=value;
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<totalVertices;i++){
            graph[i][0].color='W';
        }

        printf("\nGraph input ends");

        //BFS begins here
        printf("\nEnter the vertex from which search begins");
        int source;
        scanf("%d",&source);
        source = source - 1;

        enqueue(source);

        graph[source][0].color='G';
        graph[source][0].distance=0;

        printf("\nBFS traversal");
        while(first != NULL){
            int currentVertex = dequeue();

            for(i=0;i<totalVertices;i++){
                if(graph[currentVertex][i].data!=0){
                    if(graph[i][0].color=='W'){
                        graph[i][0].color='G';
                        graph[i][0].distance = graph[currentVertex][0].distance+1;
                        enqueue(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            graph[currentVertex][0].color='B';
            int currentVertexName = currentVertex+1;
            printf("<-> %d",currentVertex);
        }

        return 0;   
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain how to interpret your adjacency list?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not able to traverse 5"? Unless `5` is the source node you will never reach it because there are no edges to `5`.

Comment: Yes. Am not able to reach the node 5 directly. As the algorithm does not mention a loop to check for any unVisited nodes. And the adjacency list can be interpreted as the 2-4-3. Here from node 2 4 and 3 are adjacent to it.